# Android Gradle build : renaming the apk

Tags: android, build, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

How can I adapt my build.gradle to change the final basename of the apk(s) ? (without changing the default suffixes)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

On Gradle 1.8, [`project.archivesBaseName`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16794456/56285) does work, but it gives this complaint:

> Creating properties on demand (a.k.a. dynamic properties) has been
>   deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please read
>   http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html
>   for information on the replacement for dynamic properties. Deprecated
>   dynamic property: "archivesBaseName" on "root project
>   'myapp'", value: "AnotherName".

To get rid of the warning (and to avoid your build breaking on Gradle 2.0), use this:

```
project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", "AnotherName");
```

...as suggested in the [ExtraPropertiesExtension documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html).

### Update (Gradle plugin 1.1.0)

Android Gradle plugin version 1.1.0 introduced a bug which broke `archivesBaseName`, [as friederbluemle noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787493/android-gradle-build-renaming-the-apk#comment45273290_20660274). But fortunately this has since been fixed (in [version 1.1.2](https://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/gradle-plugin.html)).

Comment: Can this be combined with version code and version name ?

Comment: @Marco: not sure, I haven't done that myself. You could check if these questions help: [Change apk name with Gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22126299/56285) & [How to set versionName in APK filename using gradle?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18332474/56285). If not, ask a new specific question about that!

Comment: For some reason this stopped working with version `1.1.0-rc1` of the Android Gradle plugin. Does anyone know why?

Comment: @friederbluemle That was a bug in the plugin, but it was fixed in version 1.1.2.

Comment: @kagali-san: Why? I just verified with latest Android Gradle plugin (1.2.2) and latest Gradle (2.4) that `archivesBaseName` works fine.

Answer (score 23):

I found a very simple solution. The apk base name is the property `archivesBaseName` defined on the project. So the following line is enough to rename the apks:

```
project.archivesBaseName = "AnotherName";
```

Comment: how did you found this property? I mean, where?

Comment: I found it *somewhere* in gradle source code... but I don't remember precisely where. sorry

Comment: project.archivesBaseName = "${applicationId}-${versionName}-${versionCode}".toString()

Comment: @danik I use your snip, but got error, how to fix? error shows: `Could not get unknown property 'versionName' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

Comment: @Ninja, I use next code: 

    android { 
      defaultConfig {
          project.archivesBaseName = "${applicationId}-${versionName}-${versionCode}".toString()
`
 It works for me

Comment: @danik Thanks  for your reply.It is my misstake,use the ${versionName} in the `project.ext.set("archivesBaseName",  "${applicationId}-${versionName}-${versionCode}".toString());` Wrong scope,

Comment: @deadfish https://docs.gradle.org/4.4.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:archivesBaseName

Answer (score 11):

Starting with version 1.1.0 of the Android Gradle plugin you have to use

```
archivesBaseName = "yourOtherName"
```

instead of `project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", "yourOtherName")` in your `build.gradle` to make it work.

Comment: There was a bug with `archivesBaseName` in Android Gradle plugin that was [fixed in version 1.1.2](https://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/gradle-plugin.html). `project.ext.set` now works again.

Comment: And it is now completely broken in version 1.3.0 of the Gradle plugin. See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=182016.

Comment: @FabianFrank android gradle tools released in 1.3.1 fix this

Answer (score 2):

The below codeworked great for me on v1.3.1 and with APKs only:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        archivesBaseName = "AnotherName"
```

Again, this works with android plugin 1.3.1 (not 1.3.0) but we were still having trouble renaming both our apps (APK) and libs (AAR).  A big problem since we have a 20+ project setup where we are locking down where deployed binaries come from and not duplicate code in every sub project build.gradle.

The following worked for us:

Define the following method (and plugin) in root build.gradle:

```
ext.snapshotSuffix = "<sha>-<count>-SNAPSHOT"
ext.nextVersion = "patch"
apply plugin: 'com.cinnober.gradle.semver-git'

def renameArtifact(variant) {
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def fullName = output.outputFile.name
        def projectName = fullName.substring(0, fullName.indexOf('-'))
        output.outputFile = new File(
                (String) output.outputFile.parent,
                (String) output.outputFile.name.replace(projectName, "drivecx-${projectName}-${project.version}"))
    }
}
```

For applications use:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    ...
    // Rename all output artifacts to include version information
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        renameArtifact(variant)
    }
}
```

For libraries use:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    ...
    // Rename all output artifacts to include version information
    libraryVariants.all { variant ->
        renameArtifact(variant)
    }
}
```

Now you get some really nice files with a common prefix, project name, git-describe-wth-sha1-buildflavor, and extension.

OLD example:

```
androidauto-debug.apk
```

NEW example:

```
drivecx-androidauto-0.2.1-d1436b7-193-SNAPSHOT-debug.apk
```

A bonus is that it doesn't rename the unaligned apks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also rename the sub-project (without renaming the directory), by putting the following in the root `settings.gradle`:

```
rootProject.children.each {
    it.name = ('app' == it.name ? 'MyAppName' : it.name)
}
```

Comment: This is true, although it has the unfortunate side effect that your build commands must conform to the modified names.  In the example above, you must type './gradlew :MyAppName:build' instead of './gradlew :app:build'.