# Android Studio Gradle assembleRelease file name

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

Is it possible to specify the filename of the generated *.apk through gradle? So that I automatically could get `MyApp-1.0.0.apk` instead of the default `app-release.apk`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by adding the following line to your `build.gradle` file inside the `android{...}` part:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputFile = file("$project.buildDir/${defaultConfig.versionName}-${defaultConfig.versionCode}.apk")
}
```

**Notes:**

1. Everything inside the `file(...)` is arbitrary, of course
2. This code will output the *.apk to your `project/module/build` directory, no matter what path you've specified when Building the Signed APK.
3. The output-file will take the Name and Version-Code from your `build.gradle` file.
4. Android Studio may complain that it *"cannot resolve symbol applicationVariants/defaultConfig"* - ignore it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Got it working! Used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18334677/2078664)

```
android {
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.outputFile = new File(
                output.outputFile.parent,
                output.outputFile.name.replace(".apk", "-${variant.versionName}.apk"))
        }
    }
}
```