# How do I add a version number to my APK files using 0.14+ versions of the Android Gradle plugin?

Tags: android, gradle

I want to have the `versionName` included in the name of the output APK files from my Android build.

There's an [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18334677/125320) that works with pre-0.14.x plugin versions, but they changed some of the data model so that doesn't work anymore, and I couldn't figure out how to fix it.  As far as I can tell, the below chunk of code should work, but that last `set()` call appears to have no effect.  It doesn't throw an error, but the value isn't replaced either.

```
buildTypes {
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def oldFile = variant.outputs.outputFile.get(0)
        def newFile = new File(
                oldFile.parent,
                oldFile.name.replace(".apk", "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + ".apk"))

        variant.outputs.outputFile.set(0, newFile)
}
```

Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need one more loop now that each variant can have multiple outputs:

```
android {
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.outputFile = new File(
                    output.outputFile.parent,
                    output.outputFile.name.replace(".apk", "-${variant.versionName}.apk"))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i get an error saying it cannot find the applicationVarients property

Comment: ... and this is why we dislike gradle. you have to write code to change the freaking output file name.

Answer (score 9):

When using version 3.0.0 of the plugin or higher, you have to make a slight change:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        outputFileName = "myapp-${variant.versionName}-${variant.name}.apk"
    }
}
```

The 3.0.0 plugin [migration documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#variant_output) says:

> If you use each() to iterate through the variant objects, you need to start using all(). That's because each() iterates through only the objects that already exist during configuration time- but those object don't exist at configuration time with the new model. However, all() adapts to the new model by picking up object as they are added during execution.

Comment: This produces a warning on Gradle sync:
"'variantOutput.getPackageApplication()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getPackageApplicationProvider()'".
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54206898/variantoutput-getpackageapplication-is-obsolete) for workarounds:

Comment: This seems to work, but what about version code, which is more unique? Can be added?

Answer (score 2):

I copied your answer with some modification:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        output.outputFile = new File(
                output.outputFile.parent,
                output.outputFile.name.replace("-assistant", "-assistant-${versionName}"))
    }
}
```

the word "-assistant" is in my filename before the variant name.  Example I have 3 variants

ax, bx, cx

The filenames were in my example:

- the-assistant-ax-debug.apk
- the-assistant-bx-debug.apk
- the-assistant-cx-debug.apk

I wanted the version number in there before the variant name.  So, after the above they are now called

- the-assistant-1.0-ax-debug.apk
- the-assistant-1.0-bx-debug.apk
- the-assistant-1.0-cx-debug.apk

So, gradle build is adding the variant name in the filename for us.

The ${versionName} is simply "1.0".  And I noticed that whether it is ${versionName} or ${variant.versionName}, both produced the same result.

That is to say, if had **defaultConfig { versionName "a.b" }** and **productFlavors { ax { versionName "1.0" } }**, the **$versionName** or **$variant.versionName** in the loop in this above code will contain the variant version name "1.0"

Hope this helps someoen.