# Android Studio and Gradle: versionNameSuffix

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'd like to append special suffixes to my output APK files based on the current `buildType`. I am trying to use the standard Gradle's `versionNameSuffix` command:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
       ...
       versionNameSuffix "-XXX"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            versionNameSuffix "-YYY"
        }
        release {
            versionNameSuffix "-ZZZ"
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason none of these suffixes gets applied to the actual output file name. Does Android Studio ignore this command? Whatever I do the result is the same: `<module_name>-debug.apk` or `<module_name>-release.apk`.

Here's my config:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Does Android Studio ignore this command?

No, but `versionNameSuffix` does not affect the filename. It affects the `versionName` (`BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME`, the version name shown in Settings, etc.).

You can [teach Gradle to embed `versionName` in the APK filename](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27068573/115145), though.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's what I was looking for :)