# Need Android APK artifact to include app version in file name

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij14. I am using a Project artifact to produce a release version of the android app. The name appears to be based on the name of the Module under Project Settings.

What I'd like to do is use the android:versionName defined in my AndroidManifest.xml as a part of the APK file name. I'm not sure if there's anything in the IntelliJ build file to allow me to do this that I can see. I'm not sure what I can do short of having a post build script parse the android manifest and rename the file

I use TeamCity as my build server. If this dynamic renaming is a feature that is available only in TeamCity for some reason, that is OK.

Note: I am using an intellij project file, not a gradle build.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set versionName in APK filename using gradle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18332474/how-to-set-versionname-in-apk-filename-using-gradle)

Comment: I'm not using gradle, so this is not a duplicate question.

Comment: well, you should :). How do you build your apk on your local machine then?

Comment: LIke I said above, I'm using an IntelliJ IDEA project. I build locally using the IDE. Whether or not I should is a seperate discussion, but answering a different question doesn't help me right now.