# Android: how transfer the code version number from build.gradle in the filename .apk (app-release_v3.apk)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I need to transfer the code version number from build.gradle in the filename .apk. For example, app-release_v3.apk.

Please help to find a solution. Thank you!

Comment: Rename the file yourself.

Comment: Does this help? -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18332474/how-to-set-versionname-in-apk-filename-using-gradle

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

In build.gradle of the app module

```
android {
   ...

   defaultConfig {
      ...

      archivesBaseName = "MyAppName_v${versionName}"
   }
}
```

As result you will have `MyAppName_v3-release.apk`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This works for the "Generate Signed APK"? I've updated the code, but the file still has the old name ((

Comment: This variant helped me:     android {
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.outputFile = new File(
                    output.outputFile.parent,
                    output.outputFile.name.replace(".apk", "-${variant.versionName}.apk"))
        }
    }
}

Comment: Yes, it works for the "Generate Signed APK". I am using it in all my projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `"archivesBaseName"` properties in your `build.gradle` file.

Somenthing like:

```
defaultConfig {

   project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", "app-xxx." + defaultConfig.versionName);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This works for the "Generate Signed APK"? I've updated the code, but the file still has the old name ((

Comment: Try to use the assembleXXX command in gradle.