# Android Gradle 3.0.0-alpha2 plugin, Cannot set the value of read-only property 'outputFile'

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

i was using  this code

```
applicationVariants.all { variant -> 
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def SEP = "_"
        def flavor = variant.productFlavors[0].name
        def buildType = 
        variant.variantData.variantConfiguration.buildType.name
        def version = variant.versionName
        def date = new Date()
        def formattedDate = date.format('ddMMyy_HHmm')
        def newApkName = PROJECT_NAME + SEP + flavor + SEP + buildType + SEP + version + SEP + formattedDate + ".apk"
        def file = new File(newApkName)
        output.outputFile = file
    }
}
```

to change the name of apk file when i build new apk, but since i use the **Android Studio 3.0 Canary 2** this error appear:
**Cannot set the value of read-only property 'outputFile'....**

Comment: heres the Bad news explained, https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/new-android-plugin-migration.html#variant_api, apparently a new api is planned to resolve this. Scroll to the bottom of that links page.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

As [Android plugin 3.0 migration guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/new-android-plugin-migration.html#variant_api) suggests:

- Use `all()` instead of `each()`
- Use `outputFileName` instead of `output.outputFile` if you change only file name (that is your case)

Example from the guide:

```
// If you use each() to iterate through the variant objects,
// you need to start using all(). That's because each() iterates
// through only the objects that already exist during configuration time—
// but those object don't exist at configuration time with the new model.
// However, all() adapts to the new model by picking up object as they are
// added during execution.
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        outputFileName = "${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to change the output file path, not just name.

Comment: @AmrutBidri, I think it would be best to ask a new question (if it is not already answered somewhere on SO). This question was only for changing file name.

Comment: Yes it works, my bad, it was issue with my own plugin which checks gradle version.

Answer (score 7):

See below:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        def newApkName = applicationId + "-" + variant.versionName + "(" + variant.versionCode + ")" + ".apk";
        outputFileName = new File("${project.projectDir}/../outputs/apks/" + variant.name, newApkName);
    }
}
```

Comment: this works, but you can't change the output directory

Comment: I need to change the output file path, not just name.

Comment: getting error :  Absolute path are not supported when setting an output file name

Answer (score 4):

Below code is working for me on android studio canary 3.0.0-alpha3

```
android.applicationVariants.all {
    variant.outputs.all {
        def newApkName
        newApkName = "APPLICATION_NAME-" + defaultConfig.versionName + "-" + defaultConfig.versionCode".apk"
        outputFileName = newApkName;
    }
}
```

This change the apk file name

Comment: Could not get unknown property 'variant' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl.

Answer (score 2):

This is the ***complete example*** of this question.

Only you have to paste in your **gradle 3.0+** after productFlavours

```
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {

        def SEP = "_"
        def flavor = variant.productFlavors[0].name
        def buildType = variant.variantData.variantConfiguration.buildType.name
        def version = variant.versionName
        def versionCode = variant.versionCode
        def date = new Date();
        def formattedDate = date.format('ddMMyy_HHmm')

        outputFileName = "${flavor}${SEP}${buildType}${SEP}${version}${SEP}${versionCode}${SEP}${formattedDate}.apk"
    }
    }
```

Comment: have you paste it  in your gradle 3.0+ and after productFlavours?? you can put the especific error?

Answer (score 0):

I founded gradle 3.0 is no longer work. [source link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#test_modules)

> However, more complicated tasks that involve accessing outputFile objects no longer work. That's because variant-specific tasks are no longer created during the configuration stage. This results in the plugin not knowing all of its outputs up front, but it also means faster configuration times.

then I used command `gradlew` to compile project.and `cp`the output apk to my specified path

In Execute shell, i putted below command.

```
./gradlew clean assembleDebug
cp $WORKSPACE/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/*.apk $WORKSPACE/JenkinsApk
```

Comment: can u share the example how you did it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Error "Cannot set the value of read-only property 'outputFile'....""

So what I did is changing the version of the Android Plugin Repository to 2.3.3 in the Project Structure window. It works now and the error desappearded.

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDF6l.jpg)

Later, do Clean and Rebuild for the project and that's it

Hope this would be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a year and half since the question was asked but maybe this will help someone (like me) who discovers this post first. I believe the answer to change the file name and directory was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49530142/android-studio-3-1-buildgradle3-1-0-absolute-path-are-not-supported-when-se).

> ```
> applicationVariants.all { variant ->
>         variant.outputs.all { output ->
>             def relativeRootDir = output.packageApplication.outputDirectory.toPath()
>                      .relativize(rootDir.toPath()).toFile()
>             output.outputFileName = new File( "$relativeRootDir/release", newOutputName)
>         }
>     }
> ```

Answer (score -1):

After update to Android Studio 3.0.0 and use the new gradle, now, the output of apks will be distributed in directories by flavors name and build types.