# android studio 3.1: build:gradle:3.1.0 - Absolute path are not supported when setting an output file name

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

When I use Android Studio **3.0** and  I use the next version of **Android Gradle Plugin** in `project/build.gradle`:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

And it's work fine.
After I update to Android Studio **3.1** , as result I update **Android Gradle Plugin** :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
```

And now I get error in my `app/build.gradle`:

```
def releaseFileName = "${rootProject.name}_${defaultConfig.versionName}.apk"
outputFileName = new File(rootProject.projectDir.absolutePath + "/release", releaseFileName.toLowerCase())
```

Error:

***Absolute path are not supported when setting an output file name***

I need to put output apk (`app-release.apk`) in specific path in project. In folder `MyProject/release/app-relese.apk`. How I can do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think using "./../../../" is bad solution... I use common gradle script for several projects and I want to make code to be independency from depth of output dir.

After some researching I found this solution for gradle plugin 3.1.2:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        def relativeRootDir = output.packageApplication.outputDirectory.toPath()
                 .relativize(rootDir.toPath()).toFile()
        output.outputFileName = new File( "$relativeRootDir/release", newOutputName)
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work any more. This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55682025/8034839 is the simpler and working solution.

Answer (score 25):

Just in case this helps, this error means that now it's not allowed to have absolute paths on anything related to the apk's file name. I can attach you my BEFORE and AFTER to achieve what I needed (to have the APK in the project/app/build/ folder:

**BEFORE gradle 3.1.0**

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        outputFileName = new File(
                output.outputFile.parent,
                output.outputFile.name)
    }
}
```

**IN or AFTER gradle 3.1.0**

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        outputFileName = new File(
                "./../../../../../build/",
                output.outputFile.name)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

## The simplest **solution** for Android Gradle plugin 3.4.0+ is as below:

Assemble/concatenate your new file name:

```
def newFileName = "assemble-your-new-file-name"
```

Then, **simply assign it back**.

```
outputFileName = newFileName
```

**More specifically is as following**

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // Redirect your apks to new defined location to outputDirPath
        def outputDirPath = new File("${project.rootDir.absolutePath}/apks/${variant.flavorName}/${variant.buildType.name}")
        variant.packageApplicationProvider.get().outputDirectory = outputDirPath

        def apkFileName = "${rootProject.name}_${android.defaultConfig.versionName}.apk"
        output.outputFileName = apkFileName // directly assign the new name back to outputFileName
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the best way to get the output apk file name/path as opposed to the output directory?

Comment: @DavidBerry, `output.outputFileName` is the apk file name. But, i am not sure this is the best way or not.

Comment: at least on 5.1.1 `outputFileName` gives an unknown property error.

Comment: @DavidBerry, outputFileName is a Android Gradle plug-in property, not a Gradle build-in property. Currently, the plugin version is 3.4.2, and its corresponding Gradle version is 5.+. At least for me, this tool set works well.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51392464/8034839 for more about the version

Comment: Thanks `${rootProject.name}` this is what I am looking for

Answer (score 9):

I experienced the same issue. I haven't put the effort in to figure out exactly what's happened but there's a simple fix.

Just remove the root from your new file and trust the framework, i.e. change your code to

```
outputFileName = new File("release", releaseFileName.toLowerCase())
```

That was sufficient for us. We don't care about where the apk goes, only the name of the apk for a particular flavour.

Comment: I need to put output apk (app-release.apk) in specific path in project. In folder MyProject/release/app-relese.apk. How I can do this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough depth here. I'd need to set up gradle debugging and/or get into the sources to figure this out. My guess is there's some way to convert your path to a path relative to the project root. Quite why this change has been enforced and seemingly undocumented I don't know. Looks like you have a workaround for yourself at least :)

Answer (score 2):

I found solution:

```
def releaseFileName = "${rootProject.name}_${defaultConfig.versionName}.apk"
outputFileName = "/../../../../../release/" + releaseFileName.toLowerCase()
```

And now output file `app-release.apk` success created in `MyProject/release/app-relese.apk`

Answer (score 1):

Use `variant.packageApplicationProvider.get().outputDirectory` to avoid warning "*variantOutput.getPackageApplication() is obsolete*"

```java
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        variant.packageApplicationProvider.get().outputDirectory = new File(
            project.rootDir.absolutePath + "/release")

        def releaseFileName = "${rootProject.name}_${defaultConfig.versionName}.apk"
        output.outputFileName = releaseFileName.toLowerCase()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For gradle-6.5.1:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
          variant.outputs.all { output ->
                  outputFileName = new File("ApkName.apk")
          }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I just upgraded our project to Gradle 7.6 from 4.1.2, which removed the ability to set `outputFileName` to a relative dir.

This code below worked for me. It copies the build output from the expected directories to the directory of your choice. In my case, this was 2 levels up (../../.).

The key to this working is binding the copy task to the `assemble` tasks completion, with `finalizedBy` so it only runs after the Apk's have been created.

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        File outDir = file("${project.buildDir}/outputs/apk")
        File apkDir = file("${project.buildDir}/outputs/apk/${variant.flavorName}/${variant.buildType.name}")

        def task = project.tasks.create("publish${variant.name.capitalize()}Apk", Copy)
        task.from apkDir
        task.into outDir
        task.include "**/*"
        task.doLast {
            println ">>>publish ${variant.name} success!" +
                    "\nfrom: ${apkDir}" +
                    "\ninto: ${outDir}"
        }
        output.assemble.finalizedBy task
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append the version name and version code do it like:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all {
            def versionName = variant.versionName
            def versionCode = variant.versionCode
            def variantName = variant.name
            outputFileName = "${rootProject.name}" + '_' + variantName + '_' + versionName + '_' + versionCode + '.apk'
        }
    }
```