# Change output file name and build version

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried several solutions from this Q&A site regarding the question "how to change name of the output AAR solution from app to qpanel and how to split code from debug to release..
All in vain.. maybe because I upgraded to the last version of AS, not sure..

Whatever I changed I always get: app-debug.aar

I want just qpanel.aar without anything like debug or release at the end. Just like Visual Studio does it.

Please, explain it clear and without tricky actions.. How to change output file name to the name I want while changing build version (Debug/Release).

I don't understand why AS developers don't want to follow the same logic as in VS. Hereis the Debug folder - and dll or exe file name.. same with Release..

Please, explain this subj clear..

here is my shot:
[image]

Comment: May be this answer can help you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18334677/4995347

Comment: I'm sure there must be an easy AS GUI settings for that purpose. These tricky things they don't work for everyone.