# archiveBaseName applied to all build types

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've the following app `build.gradle`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "io.gresse.hugo.anecdote"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 12
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            archivesBaseName = "anecdote-" + defaultConfig.versionName
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
        debug {
            archivesBaseName = "anecdote-DEBUGDEBUGDEBUG-"
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute `./gradlew assembleRelease assembleDebug`

The output .apk are:
 - `anecdote-DEBUGDEBUGDEBUG-debug-unaligned.apk`
 - `anecdote-DEBUGDEBUGDEBUG-debug.apk`
 - `anecdote-DEBUGDEBUGDEBUG-release-unaligned.apk`
 - `anecdote-DEBUGDEBUGDEBUG-release.apk`

What I wanted:
 - `anecdote-DEBUGDEBUGDEBUG-debug-unaligned.apk`
 - `anecdote-DEBUGDEBUGDEBUG-debug.apk`
 - `anecdote-1.0.0-release-unaligned.apk`
 - `anecdote-1.0.0-release.apk`

Is there any way to apply the **archiveBaseName** to a specific **build types** or is it a bug?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you may notice, this question is a mess around SO.

Related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18334677/1377145) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20660274/1377145).

Here is what worked for me. I wanted to keep the simple `archiveBaseName` but it seems deprecated and that it apply to all buildTypes.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "io.gresse.hugo.anecdote"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 12
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }

    project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", "Anecdote");

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            if(variant.buildType.name == "release"){
                output.outputFile = new File(
                        output.outputFile.parent,
                        output.outputFile.name.replace(".apk", "-"+variant.versionName + ".apk"))
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If anyone wondering how to rename the APK using kotlin gradle, you can see the solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58035977/3763032

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old but multiple `archivesBaseName` still seem to overwrite each other even in the latest Gradle version (7.5).

As of Gradle 3.0 the `output` property which needs to be changed is now called `outputFileName` and is no longer an absolute path:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        if (variant.buildType.name == "release") {
            output.outputFileName = 'your-release-name.apk'
        }
    }
}
```