# How to generate output APK file with Customised name in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I want to generate output apk file using customized name. Eg. By default, android studio generates "app-debug.apk" file. But I want it to be - "MyAppName_myCurrentProdFlavour_vMyVersionName.apk"
How to do this using *build.gradle* file of module

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1. For changing app bundle name (.aab file):**

in app module's build.gradle:

```
def dateFormat = new Date().format('ddMMMyy_HHmm')
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xyz"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0.2"

        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "yourappname" + "_v" + versionName + "(" + versionCode + ")_"+dateFormat)

    }
```

For example: if your app name is XYZ then the bundle name will generated with name: **XYZ_v1.0.2(3)_28Jan22_1152-prod-release**

where,
**yourappname** is **XYZ** ,
**versionName** is **1.0.2** ,
**versionCode** is **3** ,
**dateFormat** is **28Jan22_1152** ,
and app **flavorType** and **buildType** is **prod-release**

**2. For changing apk file name (.apk file)**

in app module's build.gradle:

```
android {

applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                def name = "XYZ"
                def SEP = "_"
                def flavor = variant.productFlavors[0].name
                def buildType = variant.buildType.name
                def versionName = defaultConfig.versionName
                def versionCode = defaultConfig.versionCode
                def newApkName = name + SEP + "v" + versionName + SEP + flavor + SEP + buildType + SEP + "vc" + versionCode + SEP + dateFormat + ".apk"
                output.outputFileName = newApkName
            }
        }    
}
```

For example, if your app name is XYZ then this will generate APK file with following custom name:
**XYZ_v1.0.2_prod_release_vc3_28Jan22_1152**

---

Note: You can change dateFormat as per your requirement, for apk name if you don't have productFlavours then remove all related references from the code given above.

Answer (score 9):

#### Easiest way

Before **app_debug.apk**

After **com.pcvark.jobtest-v1(1.0)-debug.apk**

```
android {
    ..
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", applicationId + "-v" + versionCode + "(" + versionName + ")")
    }
```

**Tip** You can also set `versionNameSuffix`  for different `buildType` and variant (if you have). This will make different named apk for both `debug` and `release`.

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
          versionNameSuffix "-T"
        }
        release {
          versionNameSuffix "-R"
        }
    }
```

Further reading

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20660274/6891563

https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html

Comment: how to get applicationName in defaultConfig?

Comment: Thank you for this. Apparently the syntax updated from project.ext.set() to setProperty() at some point.

Answer (score 3):

You can customize apk file name by using this:

Go to app Gradle

```
  setProperty("archivesBaseName", "yourapp-packagename-$versionName")

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.app"
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 14       // increment with every release
        versionName '1.4.8'   // change with every release
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "yourapp-packagename-$versionName")
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following mechanism as seperately for both `debug` and `release` build which will allow you to provide **different names** for each `build`.

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    project.ext { appName = 'MY-CUSTOM-APP' }
                    def newName = output.outputFile.name
                    newName = newName.replace("app-", "$project.ext.appName-")
                    output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newName)
                }
            }
            signingConfig signingConfigs.MyApp
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    project.ext { appName = 'MY-CUSTOM-APP' }
                    def newName = output.outputFile.name
                    newName = newName.replace("app-", "$project.ext.appName-")
                    output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newName)
                }
            }
            signingConfig signingConfigs.MyApp
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Happy to help!!!

Answer (score 2):

**APK name with version and date and time.**

```
defaultConfig {
    def date = new Date()
    def formattedDate = date.format('ddMMYYYY')
    def formattedVersion = versionName
    formattedVersion = formattedVersion.replaceAll('\\.','')
    setProperty("archivesBaseName", "ApplicationName_"+formattedVersion+"_"+formattedDate)
}
```