# Rename archive Name for app with Build Variant in Android Studio 3.5

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, apk

I was building single code for multiple apk's by using below gradle code:

```
flavorDimensions "version"

    productFlavors {
        Free {
            dimension "version"
            applicationId "com.exampleFree.app"
        }
        Paid {
            dimension "version"
            applicationId "com.examplePaid.app"
        }
    }
```

Now when i build, it creates archive app as below name:

```
app-Free-debug.apk
```

When I include below code in gradle,

```
setProperty("archivesBaseName","")
```

It now creates as below APK archive name

```
-Free-debug.apk
```

I need my APK file name as below

```
Free-debug.apk
```

I was so close but how to remove that hypen `(-)` which is append in prefix ?

Comment: This may help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51888668/3809653

Comment: I have added my answer if that one solves your problem, please accept it as an answer so other future folks can have a look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can use android migration like this.

```
android {

//........
flavorDimensions "version"
productFlavors {
    Free {
        dimension "version"
        applicationId "com.exampleFree.app"
    }
    Paid {
        dimension "version"
        applicationId "com.examplePaid.app"
    }
}

applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        def appId = variant.applicationId// com.exampleFree.app OR com.examplePaid.app
        def versionName = variant.versionName
        def versionCode = variant.versionCode // e.g 1.0
        def flavorName = variant.flavorName // e. g. Free
        def buildType = variant.buildType.name // e. g. debug
        def variantName = variant.name // e. g. FreeDebug

        //customize your app name by using variables
        outputFileName = "${variantName}.apk"
    }
}}
```

Apk name **FreeDebug.apk**

**Proof**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes But i get `Free-com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ReadOnlyBuildType@2b5e6b50.apk` when i did this *outputFileName = "${flavorName}-${buildType}.apk"*

Comment: Got it! its outputFileName = "${flavorName}-${buildType.name}.apk" Thanks

Comment: @HappySingh thanks, BTW, where is it better to search for the gradle variable names like the outputFileName?

Comment: @AntonMalyshev yes that is good as per my knowledge, but there can be better ways to do it. If you'll find please let me know.

Comment: @HappySingh just wondered where did you find the variable name outputFileName...

Comment: You can have more details about this here https://developer.android.com/studio/build